# NGINX how to setup multiple locations with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

I am using nginx with multiple locations to direct requests to my site and my api.  I used certbot to generate the SSL certificate and it automatically adds lines to the nginx config to configure SSL.

The files are serving from the html folder with no problems, however, any web request to "redacted.org/api" returns a 502 Bad Gateway.  It's as if SSL is not configured for the "/api" location, but it is for the "/" location.  What do I need to change in my config (below) for this to work?

```
server {
 listen 80;

 server_name redacted.org www.redacted.org;
 location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
 location / {
    root /var/www/html;
 }

 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

 if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 } # managed by Certbot

}
```

Running on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04.2 box

Comment: Error 502 inform you about broken upstream. Nginx haven't see any process on port 5000.

Comment: I don't follow...are you saying it's _not_ a problem with the Nginx configuration?

Comment: yes. Could you check port 5000? Is there any listener?

Comment: Wow....major facepalm moment.  Somewhere along the line of me messing with Nginx, the Kestrel service that runs my .Net Core application shutdown.  I started it again and everything worked fine.  Thank you for your help and please forgive my stupidity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Move from comments**

There is problem with upstream. Error 502 shows when upstream is down. So need to check upstream and fix it.